# SCDynamicStoreCopyValueのkeyには、いったい何が指定できるんでしょうか？

Tags: swift, macos

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/systemconfiguration/1437812-scdynamicstorecopyvalue
が公式ドキュメントですが、SCDynamicStoreCopyValueのkeyに具体的に何が指定できるのか明記されていません。単に文字列が指定できることしかわかりません。

https://stackoverflow.com/a/42093698/1979953 に

> var global = SCDynamicStoreCopyValue(store, "State:/Network/Global/IPv4" as CFString)!

と

`"State:/Network/Global/IPv4"` を与えている例がありますが、他には何が指定できるのでしょうか？
他にもNetworkに関連する関数を調べていますが、与えるものが Enum ではくて文字列ばかりなので、何を指定できるのかわかりません。可能であればどのようにすれば、与えるべき文字列がわかるのかも教えていただけると幸いです。（一応GitHubで検索して他の文字列を与えている使用例は見つけましたが、この方法では場当たりすぎてどのような機能（キー）があるのか全体像がわかりません）

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> どのようにすれば、与えるべき文字列がわかるのか

きちんと記述したドキュメントは見つけられませんでしたので、この部分についてだけ。

実施に格納されている全ての情報のキーは、次のようなコードで取得できるようです。
[`SCDynamicStoreCopyKeyList`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/systemconfiguration/1437799-scdynamicstorecopykeylist)

```
import Foundation
import SystemConfiguration

let store = SCDynamicStoreCreate(nil, "test" as CFString, nil, nil)
if let list = SCDynamicStoreCopyKeyList(store, ".*" as CFString) as? [String] {
    print("\(list.count) entries")
    list.sorted().forEach {key in
        print(key)
    }
} else {
    print("SCDynamicStoreCopyKeyList->nil")
}
```

出力:

```
94 entries
Plugin:IPConfiguration
Plugin:InterfaceNamer
Plugin:KernelEventMonitor
Setup:
Setup:/
Setup:/Network/Global/IPv4
Setup:/Network/HostNames
Setup:/Network/Interface/en1/AirPort
Setup:/Network/Service/03C1116E-7462-41BB-94B6-1F6AC63FBD10
Setup:/Network/Service/03C1116E-7462-41BB-94B6-1F6AC63FBD10/IPv4
 : (略)
State:/Network/Service/F78AAAF8-DD3B-404A-A3E4-D5E037A47765/IPv4
State:/Network/mDNSResponder/DebugState
State:/Users/ConsoleUser
com.apple.DirectoryService.NotifyTypeStandard:DirectoryNodeAdded
com.apple.opendirectoryd.node:/Contacts
com.apple.opendirectoryd.node:/Search
com.apple.sharing
com.apple.sharing:/AutoUnlock/Enabled
com.apple.sharing:/AutoUnlock/InProgress
com.apple.smb
```

また同じ情報が、macOSに標準搭載されている`scutil`コマンドでも得られるようです。([参考記事](https://erikberglund.github.io/2018/Get-the-currently-logged-in-user,-in-Bash/))

```
OOPers-mini:~ dev$ scutil
> list
  subKey [0] = Plugin:IPConfiguration
  subKey [1] = Plugin:InterfaceNamer
  subKey [2] = Plugin:KernelEventMonitor
  subKey [3] = Setup:
  subKey [4] = Setup:/
  subKey [5] = Setup:/Network/Global/IPv4
  subKey [6] = Setup:/Network/HostNames
  subKey [7] = Setup:/Network/Interface/en1/AirPort
  subKey [8] = Setup:/Network/Service/03C1116E-7462-41BB-94B6-1F6AC63FBD10
  subKey [9] = Setup:/Network/Service/03C1116E-7462-41BB-94B6-1F6AC63FBD10/IPv4
    :(略)
  subKey [84] = State:/Network/Service/F78AAAF8-DD3B-404A-A3E4-D5E037A47765/IPv4
  subKey [85] = State:/Network/mDNSResponder/DebugState
  subKey [86] = State:/Users/ConsoleUser
  subKey [87] = com.apple.DirectoryService.NotifyTypeStandard:DirectoryNodeAdded
  subKey [88] = com.apple.opendirectoryd.node:/Contacts
  subKey [89] = com.apple.opendirectoryd.node:/Search
  subKey [90] = com.apple.sharing
  subKey [91] = com.apple.sharing:/AutoUnlock/Enabled
  subKey [92] = com.apple.sharing:/AutoUnlock/InProgress
  subKey [93] = com.apple.smb
> quit
OOPers-mini:~ dev$
```

各キーに対応する値がいったい何を表しているのかがわからないと意味がないかもしれませんが、「keyに具体的に何が指定できるのか」については一応わかりますよと言うことで。